# angular-auth0 with browserify says auth0 is undefined

Tags: browserify, auth0

I'm currently trying to setup auth0 for a project that I took over for at work. The project is using browserify v9.0.8 and angular 1.6. I'm following the documentation for setting up auth0-js v8.8 with angular-auth0 v2. I can get the app to inject 'auth0.auth0' but when I go into the .config file and try to inject angularAuth0Provider it tells me

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: auth0 is not defined
at /Users/bkelsey/temp/MyApp/public/js/bundle.js:52413:0 <- node_modules/angular-auth0/dist/angular-auth0.js:152:0
```

app.js

```
require('./third-party/auth0')

angular.module('MyApp', ['auth0.auth0', 'ui.router', 'moment', 'lo-dash', 'ui.bootstrap.alert', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'ui.bootstrap.dropdown', 'ui.bootstrap.datepicker', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'numberFormatter',
  'mgcrea.ngStrap.tooltip'])
  .config(require('./states.js'))
```

Snippet from states file that .config uses

```
module.exports = function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, angularAuth0Provider) {
```

The `require('.third-party/auth0)` is something that I had to do to get it to load the auth0.auth0. It is the same thing that is being done to load moment and lo-dash. This is all that's in the file.

```
var auth0 = require('auth0-js');

module.exports = angular.module('auth0.auth0', [])
  .factory('auth0', function($window) {
    return auth0; 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty fix I've found is:

in your app.js file:

```
require('./third-party/auth0/src')
----------------------------^
```

ref: https://github.com/auth0/angular-auth0/issues/28

NOTE: I've also installed: angular-auth0@beta

```
 $ npm install angular-auth0@beta -S
```